# scala slower than python in constructing a set

Tags: python, scala, performance, comparison

I am learning scala by converting some of my python code to scala code. I just encountered an issue where the python code is significantly outperforming the scala code. The code is supposed to construct a set of candidate pairs based on some conditions. Scala has comparable runtime performance with python for all previous parts.

The `id_map` is an array of map from Long to set of string. The average number of k-v pairs in the map is 1942.

The scala code snippet is below:

```scala
// id_map Array[mutable.Map[Long, Set[String]]
val candidate_pairs = id_map
      .flatMap(hashmap => hashmap.values)
      .filter(_.size >= 2)
      .flatMap(strset => strset.toList.combinations(2))
      .map(_.sorted)
      .toSet
```

and the corresponding python code is

```py
candidate_pairs = set()
for hashmap in id_map.values():
        for strset in hashmap.values():
            if len(strset) >= 2:
                for pair in combinations(strset, 2):
                    candidate_pairs.add(tuple(sorted(pair)))
```

The scala code snippet takes 80 seconds while python version takes 10 seconds.

I am wondering what can I optimize the above code to make it faster. What I have been trying is updating the set using the for loop

```scala
var candidate_pairs = Set.empty[List[String]]
for (
    hashmap: mutable.Map[Long, Set[String]] <- id_map;
    setstr: Set[String] <- hashmap.values if setstr.size >= 2;
    pair <- setstr.toList.combinations(2)
)
    candidate_pairs += pair.sorted
```

and although the `candidate_pairs` is updated a lot of time and each time it creates a new set, it actually is faster than the previous scala version, and takes about 50 seconds, still worse than python though. I tried using mutable set but however the result is about the same as the immutable version.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe make candidate_pairs a mutable set in the second version?

Comment: @AlexHall Oh yeah I forgot to mention I tried using mutable set too. However the result is about the same.

Comment: I don't know python, are you sure they are doing the same thing?

Comment: To help us, in your question, can you provide a sample of what id_map looks like?  I can definitely help optimize

Answer (score 1):

Being slower than python sounds ... surprising.

First of all, make sure you have adequate memory settings, and it is not spending half of those 80 seconds in GC.
Also, be sure to "warm up" the JVM (run your function a few times before doing actual measurement), use the *same exact data* for runs in python and scala (not just same statistics, exactly the same data), and do not include the time spent acquiring/generating data into measurement. Make several runs and compare average time, not how much a single run took.

Having said that, a few ways to make your code faster:

- Adding `.view` (or `.iterator`) after `id_map` in your implementation cuts the execution time by about factor of 4 in my experiments.
  (`.view` makes your chained transformation applied "lazily" – essentially, making a single pass through the single instance of array instead of multiple with multiple copies).

- Replacing `.map(_.sorted)` with

```
 .map {
        case List(a,b) if a < b => (a,b)
        case List(a,b) => (b, a)
      }
```

Shaves off about another 75% (sorting two element lists is mostly overhead).
This changes the return type to tuples rather than lists (constructing lots of tiny lists also adds up), but this seems even more appropriate in this case actually.

– Removing `.filter(_.size >= 2)` (it is redundant anyway, and computing size of a collection may get expensive) yields further improvement, but fairly small, that I did not bother to measure exactly.

- Additionally, it *may* be cheaper to get rid of the separate `sort` step altogether, and just add `.sorted` before `.combinations`. I have not tested it, because it would be futile without knowing more details about your data profile.

These are some general improvements that should improve your performance either way, though it is hard to be sure you'll see the same effect as I do, as I don't really know anything about your data beyond that average map size, the improvement you see might be even better than mine, or it could be somewhat smaller ... but you should see *some*.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this version with some test Scala code I created. On a list of 1944 elements, it completed in about 15 ms on my laptop.

```scala
id_map
  .flatMap(hashmap => hashmap.values)
  .flatMap { strset =>
    if (strset.size >= 2) {
      strset.toIndexedSeq.combinations(2)
    } else IndexedSeq.empty
  }.map(_.sorted).toSet
```

Main changes I have are to use an `IndexedSeq` instead of a `List` (which is a LinkedList), and to do the filter on the fly.

I assume you didn't want to hyper optimize, in which case you could still remove a lot of the intermediate collections created in the flatMap, combinations, conversion to IndexedSeq and toSet call.

Comment: Run the original code on the same data, see how long that takes.

Comment: I got about 33 ms on the original.  I'm really confused how yours is running 80 seconds on less than 2 thousand elements.  Can you provide a sample file @Dima?  I like optimization problems and this is interesting.

Comment: Mine isn't :) The OP's is ... (I am not the OP).  "less than 2 thousand elements" is the _average size of the map_.  We don't know how many maps there are in the array. 
I am surprised that you changes make any difference to performance at all ... but the numbers seem to be small enough for it to just be a random fluctuation. Try running your simulation like 1000 times with and without your changes and comparing the averages (or just how long 1000 runs take).

Comment: Ahh, good catch that the 2k was the average size of the maps.  So this could be a ton of data.  Would be good to have additional information from OP.   It informs how much any optimization is worth it. Right now there's not much difference after benchmarking.

Comment: 80 seconds sounds pretty worthy of optimization ... especially, if it is indeed 8 times slower than same thing in python :)